# Need to create class diagram from C# Class and print it

Tags: c#, class, class-diagram

for a medium project, I need create class diagram from class code (plain text class with public properties), and print it.
This for more develop code and project organization. Which tools I can use?

Comment: try draw.io if you want to make it manually

Comment: Use visual studio professional. It has class diagrams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio,Solution

```
 Explorer=>
          classFileName=>
                      right Click on it(open Context menu)=>
                                                Select Class Diagram option
```

Comment: Hi, this is a good solution, but I'm searching some external tools that I can use also for documentation. Thanks

Comment: you can also use draw.io online diagram creator and select new diagram and choose software category

Comment: Thanks. But I need create diagram from class. Visual Studio Solution is now the best solution. Thanks.